# How to interpret the results from logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, odds-ratio

I have a binary variable y, and categorical variables $x1$, $x2$, $x3$, and $x4$.

I conducted a series of logistic regressions

```
y ~ x1, # (getting crude OR)
y ~ x1+x2,
y ~ x1+x3,
y ~ x1+x4,
y ~ x1+x2+x3,
```

Results are below

[image]

- Crude ORs monotonically increase as shown in column 2,
- ORs adjusted for $x2$ monotonically increase as shown in column 3,
- ORs adjusted for $x3$ monotonically increase as shown in column 4,

But

- ORs adjusted for $x2$  and $x3$ monotonically increase until $x1=4$, then had a dip for $x1=5$, as shown in column 6,
- ORs adjusted for $x4$ monotonically increase until $x1=4$, then had a dip for $x1=5$,  as shown in column 5,

How to interpret why there was a dip for $x_1=5$ when adjusted for $x_4$ or adjusted for $x2+x3$?

please see below for ORs with standard error (SE)

[image]

Comment: What are the standard errors for all these ORs?  It could just be random fluctuations in the estimating process.

Comment: Please see above for standard  errors